# Error CordovaModuleLoadError - multi device hybrid app in visual studio

Tags: ios, git, cordova, npm, visual-studio-cordova

I am following the steps [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn757054.aspx#ios) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757056.aspx) to build and simulate a multi device hybrid app in ios.

I followed the steps in the articles and I can see that when I run my multi device hybrid app in visual studio using iphone simulator as the run target, the connected mac device response to the build request. However, the mac terminal will end the build process with the following build error:

```
Done building  5116: error CordovaModuleLoadError  [ '3.5.0-0.2.4' ]
```

And here is the full terminal output:

```
 IBRAHIM-ALHUSSAINs-Mac-mini:cordova IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN$ vs-mda-remote --secure false
vs-mda-remote
Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
0.2.11

Loading resources for language en from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vs-mda-remote/resources/en/resources.json
Build Retention initialized with baseBuildDir /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds, maxBuildsToKeep 20
Initialized BuildManager with baseBuildDir /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds; maxBuildsInQueue 10; deleteBuildsOnShutdown true; allowsEmulate true; nextBuildNumber 5115
Remote build server listening on [http] port 3000
ios-sim is installed on path at: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vs-mda-remote/node_modules/ios-sim/build/release/ios-sim

New build request submitted:
/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=3.5.0-0.2.4&cfg=release
{ 'accept-language': 'en-US',
  host: '192.168.1.11:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked' }
New build request submitted for cordovaVersion: 3.5.0-0.2.4; buildCommand: build; configuration: release
Build will be executed under: /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds/5116
Saving build request payload to : /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds/5116
Saved upload to /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds/5116/upload_5116.tgz
Extracting /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds/5116/upload_5116.tgz to /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds/5116/cordovaApp...
POST /build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=3.5.0-0.2.4&cfg=release 202 1279ms - 529b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 3ms - 529b
Extracted app contents from uploaded build request to /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds/5116/cordovaApp. Requesting build.
Taking 5116 as current build
Building cordova app B8ak بيتك at appDir /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds/5116/cordovaApp
Opened build log file /Users/IBRAHIMALHUSSAIN/remote-builds/builds/5116/build.log
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 2ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 0ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 2ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 0ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 0ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 0ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 0ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 0ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 0ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 2ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 0ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 0ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 1ms - 625b
Done building 5116 : error CordovaModuleLoadError [ '3.5.0-0.2.4' ]
Done with currentBuild. Checking for next build in queue.
GET /build/tasks/5116 200 2ms - 667b
GET /build/tasks/5116/log 200 4ms
```

Comment: are you using vs 2015 Community RC or vs 2013 Community update 4 with cordova ctp3.1?

Comment: I am actually using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 update 3. I am not sure if this answer your question but I went to VS -> Help -> About to get this version and update info.

Comment: I'm using vs 2015 Community rc, the freeofcharge version, without any problem to debug my app in my Mac Mini.  You may need to upgrade your vs as microsoft said the 2013 version of cordova will be deprecated!

Comment: my cordova version in 2015 is 4.3.0

Comment: Is it possible to update the corodva version without updating visual studio? Or is corodova version bounded by the version of my visual studio?

Comment: don't try to update the cordova version, it's troublesome!  don't upgrade vs 2013, just install 2015, they can co-exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indicates you are using CTP2 of tools for Apache Cordova. Moving to CTP3.1 or VS 2015 RC should resolve your issue.

VS 2015 will also allow you to select the version of Cordova you use though you could see problems with a year old release like Cordova 3.5.0. The default in VS 2015 of 4.3.0 should be compatible and contains numerous bug fixes including security improvements.

VS 2015 will be the supported version of Tools for Apache Cordova. Previous releases were only technology previews.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am now facing [another issue here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580895/cordovamoduleloaderror-4-3-0-multi-device-hybird-app-in-visual-studio)